# Ordenar array bidimensional por índice data (timestamp)

Tags: php, array, classificação

Tenho o seguinte *array* que contem informações de arquivos de uma pasta:

```
    Array
    (
        [name] => Apresenta__o1.ppt
        [server_path] => C:\wamp\www\portais\arquivos\alunos\4_45258\files\Apresenta__o1.ppt
        [size] => 174080
        [date] => 1432943066
        [relative_path] => C:\wamp\www\portais\arquivos/alunos/4_45258/files
        [ext] => Array
            (
                [0] => application
                [1] => powerpoint
            )

        [i_empresa] => 4
        [i_aluno] => 45258
    )
    Array
    (
        [name] => Apresenta__o2.jpg
        [server_path] => C:\wamp\www\portais\arquivos\alunos\4_45258\files\Apresenta__o2.jpg
        [size] => 68710
        [date] => 1432943064
        [relative_path] => C:\wamp\www\portais\arquivos/alunos/4_45258/files
        [ext] => Array
            (
                [0] => image
                [1] => jpeg
            )

        [i_empresa] => 4
        [i_aluno] => 45258
    )
    Array
    (
        [name] => Atendimento_Comunicativo.doc
        [server_path] => C:\wamp\www\portais\arquivos\alunos\4_45258\files\Atendimento_Comunicativo.doc
        [size] => 28672
        [date] => 1434671499
        [relative_path] => C:\wamp\www\portais\arquivos/alunos/4_45258/files
        [ext] => Array
            (
                [0] => application
                [1] => msword
            )

        [i_empresa] => 4
        [i_aluno] => 45258
    )
```

**Como ordenar esse *array* pelo índice `date`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar a função `usort` e criar uma função para a regra:

**Valor Numérico:**

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b){
    return $a['date'] - $b['date'];
});
```

**String:**

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b){
    strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/u8f9-ngtk)

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699159/3497987)

Answer (score -4):

Tenta assim:

```
$array_total = array($array_com_informacoes_1, $array_com_informacoes_2...);

arsort($array_total); //mais recentes primeiro
            ou
asort($array_total); //mais antigos primeiro

var_dump($array_total); //Agora vc tem um array com todos os outros, de forma ordenada
```

código exemplo:

```
    $itens = array(Array
(
    'name' => 'Apresenta__o2.jpg',
    'server_path' => 'C:\wamp\www\portais\arquivos\alunos\4_45258\files\Apresenta__o2.jpg',
    'size' => 68710,
    'date' => 1432943064,
    'relative_path' => 'C:\wamp\www\portais\arquivos/alunos/4_45258/files',
    'ext' => Array
        (
            '0' => 'image',
            '1' => 'jpeg'
        ),

    'i_empresa' => 4,
    'i_aluno' => 45258,
),
Array
(
    'name' => 'Atendimento_Comunicativo.doc',
    'server_path' => 'C:\wamp\www\portais\arquivos\alunos\4_45258\files\Atendimento_Comunicativo.doc',
    'size' => 28672,
    'date' => 1434671499,
    'relative_path' => 'C:\wamp\www\portais\arquivos/alunos/4_45258/files',
    'ext' => Array
        (
            '0' => 'application',
            '1' => 'msword'
        ),

    'i_empresa' => 4,
    'i_aluno' => 45258
));
arsort($itens);//Mais recentes primeiro 
var_dump($itens);
```

Comment: não funcionou, retorna 1 para cada array

Comment: As funções acima, ordenam por referência, sendo assim você pode tentar isso: Coloque todos os arrays retornados em um único array, depois utilize uma das funções acima para organizar esse array, pronto vc tem um array com todos os outros ordenados dentro dele, vou editar a resposta...

Comment: tentei de todas essas formas e todas retornam 1 e não a array reordenada

Comment: nada, o mesmo retorno 1 sempre